Please help with literature for Lyapunov stability for non-linear observer
I'm working with an approximation-based observer design for reaction-diffusion PDE, where I apply the Petrov-Galerkin approximation to a non-linear PDE and get the following ODE:
$$\dot{\beta} = A\beta - \beta \circ\beta,  \quad y = C\beta, \quad \forall t > 0,$$
with initial condition $\beta(0) = \beta_0$. Here, $\beta = \beta(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the temporal coordinate, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\circ$ is the Hadamard product. $y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the observation vector with $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that $(A, C)$ is observable.
I want to design a full state observer in the form:
$$\dot{\hat{\beta}} = A\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta} \circ\hat{\beta} + K(y - C\hat{\beta}) \quad \forall t > 0,$$
With observer gain $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. In order to show that the observed states converge to the states of the original system, I went the Lyapunov stability-based route:
Let the approximation error be $e = \beta - \hat{\beta}$, and consider the Lyapunov function candidate $$V = \frac{1}{2}e^\top e > 0,\quad \forall e \neq 0.$$
If we differentiate in time, we get
$$\dot{V} = e^\top \dot{e} = e^\top[(A-KC)e-\beta \circ\beta + \hat{\beta} \circ\hat{\beta}] = 
e^\top[(A-KC)e-(\beta +\hat{\beta}) \circ e],
$$
Or using other notations
$$ \dot{V} = e^\top \underbrace{[(A-KC)e-\mathrm{diag}(\beta +\hat{\beta})]}_M e .$$
Now, if this would be a simple linear case, choosing $K$ such that $A-KC$ is Hurwitz would mean that $\dot{V} < 0$, which would prove that $\hat{\beta} \to \beta$ asymptotically.
In my case, there is a state-dependent term that is not even Lipschitz continuous.
Even showing that the original system is positive and bounded (which it is according to simulations) requires the Lipschitz continuousness.
Do you have any good literature that would help me in this final step of the proof? Or Should I use some other method?
I already tested this observer in simulation, and in every scenario, it works, so this is clearly only a me problem.

Which initial conditions have you tried in your simulations?

The original PDE was Fisher’s equation with three different initial conditions: sech^2(x), exp(-x^2), and a piece-wise exponential function with flat middle. Of course, these were discretised on a [-l,l] domain using 5, 7 and 11 points for the Petrov-Galerkin approximation.
